VBA script is not assigning variable
In my VBA script, I have for debugging purposes created variables tt and ttl. Why is my tt variable showing a value and my ttl is showing empty ("")?
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("STEPS") ' Change "Sheet1" to your actual sheet name

' Determine the last row
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Create a dictionary to hold unique names and concatenated texts
Set data = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' Loop through each row in column A
For i = 1 To lastRow
    Dim name As String
    name = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value

    If Not data.exists(name) Then
        data.Add name, Array("", "") ' Initialize with empty strings for G and H
    End If
    
    ' Concatenate column G
    If data(name)(0) = "" Then
        Dim tt As String
        tt = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
        data(name)(0) = tt
        Dim ttl As String
        ttl = data(name)(0)
        
      '  data(name)(0) = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
    Else
        data(name)(0) = data(name)(0) & ", " & ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
    End If


An array stored as a value in a dictionary is non-mutable, you need to remove the dictionary entry and replace it with a new array.

As stated above, an array item cannot be changed directly! A Scripting Dictionary is a very powerful object able to keep (almost) everything as item: strings, numbers, objects(collections, classes, other dictionaries etc.) and arrays. All items except an array can be changed directly. When you try changing the item array (data(name)) it returns a temporary copy of the array! data(name)(0) refers to the first element of the temporary copy of the array. You can use it to extract each element and do whatever you need, but after using the object it is destroyed (its memory reference)

You can check that Debug.Print VarPtr(data(name)(0)) (to obtain its address) for some times and you will obtain different addresses. This means that after evaluation it is destroyed and released from memory. It is not possible to refer it after that... That's why you need to extract the item in an array variable, modify it (ReDim Preserve and add a new element, change existing items etc.) and then place the array back as that dictionary item.

As Warcupine wrote in the comments, an array as value of a dictionary is inmutable - that means the content cannot be changed.
What happens when you write data(name)(0) = tt:

The value of the dictionary with the key name is located.
As this value is an array, a copy of the array is created (in memory)
You modify the first element of that copied array.
The array inside the dictionary remains unchanged.

With the statement ttl = data(name)(0) the same thing happens again: A copy of the array is created in memory. The first element of that array is assigned to ttl, but as this first element never got any value, ttl will always be empty.
Instead of using an array, consider to use an object. Create a simple class that holds the data you want to store. Of course you can create getter and setter for every property of the class, but basically it is sufficient to write
Public valueOfColG As String
Public valueOfColH As String

I don't know what data you store, name the properties how ever you want. I named the class clsData, again, name it how ever you want. Now every time you add a new entry to the dictionary, you create a new object. You can change the properties of the object - the dicionary holds just a reference to it, not the data itself.
Your code would look like this:
Dim myDetailData as clsData

If Not data.exists(name) Then
    myDetailData = new clsData
    myDetailData.valueOfColG = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
    data.Add name, myDetailData
Else
    Set myDetailData = data(name)
    myDetailData.valueOfColG = myDetailData.valueOfColG & ", " & ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
End If

As myDetailData holds the same reference as the dictionary element, modifying a property of the object will modify the object inside the dictionary itself (and not a copy).

If you want to continue with an array:
Dim tmp
'...
'...

For i = 1 To lastRow
    
    name = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value
    If Not data.Exists(name) Then data.Add name, Array("", "") 'initialize an array if needed
    
    tmp = data(name)  'pull out the array
    tmp(0) = tmp(0) & IIf(Len(tmp(0)) > 0, ", ", "") & ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
    data(name) = tmp  'return the modified array


Modify Values in Nested Dictionaries

You cannot change the values of an array in a dictionary (a workaround is illustrated in Tim Williams' post).
But you can change the values in an object (e.g. Collection, Dictionary, or a Class as illustrated in FunThomas' post).
The following uses a dictionary i.e. for each key of the main (outer) dictionary, the corresponding item is another (inner) dictionary.

The Code
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "STEPS"
    Const SRC_NAME_COLUMN As String = "A"
    Const SRC_FIRST_ROW As Long = 2
    Dim SRC_OTHER_COLUMNS As Variant: SRC_OTHER_COLUMNS = VBA.Array("G", "H")
    Const DELIMITER As String = ", "
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    
    ' Determine the last row
    Dim sLastRow As Long:
    sLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, SRC_NAME_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row
    If sLastRow < SRC_FIRST_ROW Then Exit Sub ' no data
    
    ' Determine the number of columns (inner dictionary elements).
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long: ColumnsCount = UBound(SRC_OTHER_COLUMNS) + 1
    
    ' Create a reference to a dictionary object.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare  ' case-insensitive r.e. 'A=a'
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim idict As Object, Value As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim Name As String, ValueString As String
    
    ' Loop through the rows...
    For r = SRC_FIRST_ROW To sLastRow
        Value = ws.Cells(r, SRC_NAME_COLUMN).Value
        If Not IsError(Value) Then
            If Len(Value) > 0 Then
                Name = CStr(Value)
                ' Use the name as the key, and as the item,
                ' add a new (inner) dictionary
                ' that has as many as 'ColumnsCount' elements
                ' whose keys are the numbers from 1 to 'ColumnsCount',
                ' and each corresponding item is an empty string.
                If Not dict.Exists(Name) Then
                    Set idict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                    For c = 1 To ColumnsCount
                        idict.Add c, vbNullString
                    Next c
                    dict.Add Name, idict
                End If
                ' Loop through the columns...
                For c = 1 To ColumnsCount
                    Value = ws.Cells(r, SRC_OTHER_COLUMNS(c - 1)).Value
                    If Not IsError(Value) Then
                        If Len(Value) > 0 Then
                            ValueString = CStr(Value)
                            If Len(dict(Name)(c)) = 0 Then ' first (as is)
                                dict(Name)(c) = ValueString
                            Else ' remaining (join (concat))
                                dict(Name)(c) = dict(Name)(c) _
                                    & DELIMITER & ValueString
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next c
            End If
        End If
    Next r
 
    ' Return all values with e.g.:
    
    Dim oKey As Variant, iKey As Variant
    
    For Each oKey In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print "Outer Key: " & oKey
        For Each iKey In dict(oKey).Keys
            'If Len(dict(oKey)(iKey)) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Inner Key: " & iKey, "Inner Value: " & dict(oKey)(iKey)
            'End If
        Next iKey
    Next oKey
    
    ' Return specific values with e.g.:
    Debug.Print "First:     " & dict("Peter")(2)
    Debug.Print "Second:    " & dict("Sue")(1)
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Done.", vbInformation
 
End Sub


The Result in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G)
Outer Key: Peter
Inner Key: 1  Inner Value: GP1, GP9
Inner Key: 2  Inner Value: HP1, HP6, HP9
Outer Key: Mary
Inner Key: 1  Inner Value: GM2, GM5, GM7
Inner Key: 2  Inner Value: HM5, HM7, HM8
Outer Key: Sue
Inner Key: 1  Inner Value: GS3, GS4
Inner Key: 2  Inner Value: HS4
Outer Key: John
Inner Key: 1  Inner Value: GJ10
Inner Key: 2  Inner Value: HJ10
First:     HP1, HP6, HP9
Second:    GS3, GS4

